# Unable to listen for new mails. folder.addMessageCountListener() not working

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I am developing an email client app in android. For these i'm implementing a **IMAP** client using **Java-Mail** API.I have also added `folder.addMessageCountListener` ,but unable to listen for new email's. I have also tried with **folder.idle()**, but not succeed. Below is the code i'm using :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
      mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
      mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
      mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
      mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
      mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
      CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);

      Properties properties = getServerProperties("imap", "mail.xyz.com", "143");

      try {
         Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
         Store store = session.getStore("imap");

         store.connect(txt_name.getText().toString().trim(), txt_pwd.getText().toString().trim());
         Folder[] f = store.getDefaultFolder().list();

         // opens the inbox folder
         folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
         folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

         //how many emails in the inbox
         int count = folderInbox.getMessageCount();

         folderInbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
         @Override
         public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent messageCountEvent) {
            System.out.println("New Mails event fired.");
            }

         @Override
         public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent messageCountEvent) {

            }
         });
         if (folderInbox instanceof IMAPFolder) {
            IMAPFolder fol = (IMAPFolder)folderInbox;
            fol.idle();
         }              
      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}).start();
```

Here is my **Java Mail Debug** Output. Complete debug report.

```
I/System.out: DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
I/System.out: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method javax.mail.Session com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getSession() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in javax.mail.Service
             14727-14872/com.imapmailapp I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "mail.abc.com", port 993, isSSL false
I/System.out: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
I/System.out: A0 CAPABILITY
I/System.out: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
I/System.out: A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
              [ 11-14 19:57:05.837 14727:14872 W/         ]
              Unable to open '/system/framework/timakeystore.jar': No such file or directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/timakeystore.jar': I/O Error
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=mail.abc.com, user=test@abc.com, password=<non-null>
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
I/System.out: A2 CAPABILITY
I/System.out: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
I/System.out: A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
I/System.out: A3 LIST "" "%"
I/System.out: A3 OK LIST completed.
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
I/System.out: A4 SELECT INBOX
I/System.out: * 0 EXISTS
I/System.out: * 0 RECENT
I/System.out: * FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
I/System.out: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
I/System.out: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
I/System.out: * OK [UIDNEXT 7] The next unique identifier value
I/System.out: A4 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
I/System.out: A5 IDLE
I/System.out: + IDLE accepted, awaiting DONE command.
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: set to IDLE
I/System.out: DEBUG IMAP: startIdle: return true
```

Comment: See the JavaMail sample program [monitor.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/monitor.java) for a complete example.  You need to either use the IMAP IDLE command to wait for notifications, or you need to periodically poke the server to give it a chance to deliver notifications.

Comment: @BillShannon First of all thanks for your great work in Java-Mail . Second, If i poke to server periodically , will it not use more internet data usage ?

Comment: Yes.  The alternative is to use the IMAP IDLE command.  Again, there's an example in monitor.java.  Note that, even with IDLE, the server is going to time out the connection after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: @BillShannon I have used **folder.idle()** , but can't succeed .Still same not getting any notification for new mails.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: @BillShannon It gets connected in command line. And shows a empty black screen. With no errors.

Comment: Then you haven’t enabled the JavaMail debug output properly.

Comment: @BillShannon I have added debug output in the post.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you’re actually calling the idle method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159023/discussion-between-prashant-kumar-sharma-and-bill-shannon).

Comment: Also, you’re using a very old version of JavaMail.  Make sure you’re using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Comment: @BillShannon I have upgraded the API to latest ver. 1.6.0 . And the result is same. Above debug report is also added.

Comment: Ok, now you’re definitely calling idle.  If you’re sending messages to that account then it looks like the server at mail.abc.com is broken since it’s not notifying you of the new messages.  You may have to resort to polling for new messages instead of using the IDLE command.

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks alot. Will go for that.

Comment: @BillShannon Now i am able to listen for new mails, but i have a problem. I can only listen for only 1 new mails, for other new mails folder.addMessageCountListener won't work . I am unable to listen for more new mails after i have received the first one. Code is the same above enlisted.

Comment: The code above is using IDLE.  I thought you determined that your server doesn't support IDLE?  If you're now using a server that does support IDLE, you need to call the idle method in a loop, as described in the [javadocs for the idle method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle--) and as illustrated in the monitor.java program linked above.